# How to sort first asc after desc Jquery and return state initial

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, effect

I have an unordered list and then the ordered ascendant descending and return to the initial state with a single button, this is what I have for now, thanks

http://jsbin.com/eculis/1405/

passed through three states, ascending, descending, and restore, its need

Comment: where is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your `dec_sort` function, just switch the order of the `a` and `b` argument variables.

```
function dec_sort(a, b){ //instead of b, a
    return ($(b).text()) > ($(a).text()) ? 1 : -1;    
}
```

Also, store the contents of your `.list` tag:

```
var original = $('.list').html();
```

So when you want to restore the list, you can do:

```
$('.list').html(original);
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eculis/1406/)

Comment: passed through three states, ascending, descending, and restore, thanks